# Is there a quaint hotel in Venice Beach?

Tags: hotels, southern-california

We don't like chrome and mirrors, fancy hotels. e.g. a Marriott is about as far away from our ideal as I could imagine. We would prefer something old fashioned relaxed, small, family and friendly.

Oh yes we like the beach and would ideally be close to it.

Why Venice Beach?  I have relations who live there.

Answer (score 7):

I nearly closed this as what defines "quaint" is subjective and ambiguous, but I decided to give it a shot and include reviews from visitors who have described hotels there as "quaint".  Result was two hotels, one being more likely than the other.

- **The Georgian Hotel** - 1415 Ocean Ave., Santa Monica, CA 90401, is described as “Very **Quaint** hotel, Fabulous Position on the Pier, Most of the staff were helpful” on [Trip Advisor](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g33052-d82036-r109430850-The_Georgian_Hotel-Santa_Monica_California.html).
- **Shutters on the Beach** - 1 Pico Blvd, Santa Monica, CA 90405 sounds like your best bet considering your requirements - "Shutters is an amazing hotel located at the beach, very **quaint** and high end. The lobby area is dimly lit and adorned with candles, multiple sofas mostly positioned in front of fireplaces which makes for a very cozy evening. " - 
  as seen on [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/biz/shutters-on-the-beach-santa-monica).

Hope that helps!